# How can I get the coordinates of a grid cell?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba, vb.net

How can I get the real coordinates (i.e. X and Y) of a given grid cell when I know its row and column position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know row, column, cellsize and extent, X & Y can easily be calculated. Note this assumes a North up raster. If the raster is rotated you'll need to know the other two [affine transformation coefficients](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723070206/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_datamodel.html#gdal_datamodel_dataset_gtm) (or geotransform in GDAL speak). Also note that the column/row coordinates in the below are from (0.0,0.0) at the upper left corner of the upper left pixel. To get the coordinates of the centre of the column/row location you need to add 0.5 to the column and row values.

```
mapx = xmin + col*cellsize
mapy = ymax - row*cellsize
```

See also the IRaster2.PixelToMap Method ([9.3 reference](https://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriDataSourcesRaster/IRaster2_PixelToMap.htm) and [10 reference](https://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PixelToMap_Method/001q00000232000000/))

Comment: Luke:How can I determine the Xmin and Ymax in the above formulas?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add links to the IRaster2.PixelToMap method.